# OpenCV selecting proper submatrix in loop with C++

Tags: c++, matrix, opencv, submatrix

I'm fairly new to opencv.  I'm trying to write a loop that does some processing on a small (9x9) submatrix of a large (~1000 x ~1000) matrix.  Based on some mask matrix I decided whether or not to process the 9x9 at a particular point in the large matrix.  Based on the documentation I read I'm trying to put this line of code inside a loop:

```
Mat tempROI(*(data->cvData), Rect(i-4,j-4, i+5, j+5));
```

i and j are row,col indecies of the larger matrix.  I then have a function that processes tempROI.  I'm finding, however, that the size of my ROI is increasing with i and j.  I dumped a:

```
printf("Size of ROI = %d, %d.\nFor IDX = %d, %d\n", tempROI.rows, tempROI.cols, i, j);
```

into the loop to debug.  I see that my ROI is increasing significantly.  For example here's a random dump:

Size of ROI = 191, 9.
For IDX = 4, 186

Clearly something's not working properly and I think it's a fair assumption that the fallacy lies in my understanding of how to properly select a submatrix from a larger one.  Can someone advise as to what the best way to go about this is?

On a related note I was really hoping to just use a pointer as opposed to actually creating the matrix header every loop iteration.

In short - what's the right way to do what I'm trying to do?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: It appears as though my lack of understanding was actually in the way Rect is defined.  I assumed that it was top left point/bottom right point, but it is in fact top left point, width, height.  That said, I really doubt this is the most efficient manner to do what I'm trying to do.  Any thoughts would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What's with `*(data->cvData)`? Can't you just use the large matrix object directly?

Comment: It's "processing" dependent. What are you trying to do with these 9x9 windows?